# Unable to execute plink command using groovy script

Tags: android, groovy, ssh, adb, plink

I got stuck in a issue with **plink** command running on windows.Below is the command I am firing to drop iptable of remote android device.

**plink.exe -v -ssh rauser@HOSTNAME -pw PASSWORD iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5555 -j DROP**

I am  able to execute the command from command prompt manually but when I am executing command as a bat file from groovy script it throws me an error.I am sharing both with you.

**Groovy Script**

```
// enable ADB
commandsList.add(""
    "enable-adb.bat "
    "" + deviceip)
// run adb commands
commandsList.each {
        def command = pathtoadb + it
        log.info command
        def proc = command.execute()
        proc.waitFor() // Wait for the command to finish
        // Obtain status and output
        log.info "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}" // "0" is success
        //log.info "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
        log.info "stdout: ${proc.in.text}" // *out* from the external program is *in* for groovy
        def error = proc.err.text;
        // if the output contains "Bad rule" that means ADB is already enabled and we don't want the test to fail
        if (!error.contains("Bad rule")) {
            log.info "  _______  There was a problem connecting to your device using SSH. Check if remote access is enabled on your device"
            log.info("ERROR:   " + error)
        } else {
            log.info "  _______  return code is 1 because ADB was already enabled - this is not a failure"
            log.info("        ********    ADB has been enabled on device -->  " + deviceip)
        }
```

**Exeception Message**

```
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.62
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Server unexpectedly closed network connection
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

Comment: For a start, I'd suggest you to upgrade to the latest version of Plink/PuTTY.

Comment: Kindly mention the reason of down vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. But as you didn't take my advice, and are still using **7 years old version** of security software, you deserve the downvote.

Comment: okay! First of all thank you for the suggestion.I am working with some new versions of plink. Just wanted some more thoughts on the it.:).Also I want to mention again ,same command is working from command line fine.So I was less hoping that it's plink version issue.

Comment: Make sure that groovy executes the same version of plink as you execute from command-line. You may have two copies.

Comment: Yes.I have assured that already.I am using same exe file for both.